# phpmyadmin fails to load "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Class 'PMA_Message' not found in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Message.class.php"

Tags: nginx, mysql, centos6, php-fpm, phpmyadmin

After upgrading some of the php libraries on our server phpmyadmin failed to load.

I see the following error on my web browser when trying to access browser

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.
```

This is the error I see in the log files.

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin/error.log

2015/09/16 12:54:13 [error] 9103#0: *21314 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: PMA_Error::$_hash in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Error.class.php on line 164
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: PMA_Error::$_params in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Message.class.php on line 495
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PMA_Message' not found in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Message.class.php on line 601" while reading upstream, client: 123.456.789.123, server: server12-admin.smokeccs.com, request: "GET /index.php?token=b07fa5dd143c2c9ec26042ee527121ba HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "server12-admin.smokeccs.com", referrer: "http://server12-admin.smokeccs.com/index.php?token=96f06e54e731f866b4b22f8abd46b7c2"
```

Our server details

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: Percona Server
Server version: 5.6.22-71.0 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 71.0, Revision 726
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

nginx/1.6.2
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation

Phpmyadmin version
Version information: 4.0.10.8, latest stable version: 4.4.14.1
```

Answer (score 1):

After some [googling](https://yuvrajingale.wordpress.com/2015/01/23/php-fatal-error-class-pma_message-not-found/) the issue was linked to permision on sessions folder phpmyadmin was using.

```
chown root:nginx /var/lib/php/session/
```